# Validation Rule Question

Tags: validation, validation-rule

How to create a validation rule where in if I edit a certain field for example `Total_Discount__c` in the object `Opportunity` it will throw an error because an `OpportunityLineItem` is present. `OpportunityLineItem` has a lookup to the object `Opportunity`.

Comment: Add a roll-up field on the Opportunity, based on the `OpportunityLineItem` relationship, and set the validation rule formula to `OpportunityLineItemSum__c > 0`.

Comment: I need to create the validation rule on the Opportunity Object @battery.cord

Comment: @battery.cord Not necessary to make a custom rollup.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Ill be sure to remember that in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HasOpportunityLineItem field tells you there's products on an opportunity, and ISCHANGED tells you if a field value has changed, so:

```
HasOpportunityLineItem && ISCHANGED(Total_Discount__c)
```

Comment: Sorry for the edits, I forgot about ISCHANGED.

Comment: I have a question. Why is my question downvoted?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I tried your code and it throws an Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'or()'. Expected Boolean, received Number

Comment: @JMDF Thanks for asking about the downvote. Unfortunately, I can't know for sure, but you'll want to read [ask] for how you can improve your questions in the future. We encourage questions that demonstrate some research before approaching this community with the question. As for the error you've mentioned, my formula doesn't have an OR() anywhere in it, so you most likely have a syntax problem elsewhere.